# jquery: submit form does not work

Tags: jquery, forms

i have an almost simular problem as posted before.
My first problem has been solved, but now i am trying for 2 hours to solve the next one.

After confirming, my form has to be submitted.
I have a long list of forms, and wit a class forced to a jquery confirmation message.
I can get the name of the used form and data fromthat form (solution provided by one of you!).

The name or id of the form to be sent is stored in a variable. I have tried both: name an id of the form, both dont work in my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".confirm_submit").click( function(){ 
var confirmteamnaam = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='teamnaam']").val();
var frmnaam = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
jConfirm( confirmteamnaam  + frmnaam, function(r) {
    if(r == true)
    {
        $(frmnaam).submit(); // this doe not work??
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
});
return false;
```

});

In the confirmation text the names are displayed correctly.
Tried it with id and name of the form, both dont submit?

many thanks in advance for any solution!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your form selector an id selector:

```
$('#' + frmnaam).submit();
```

---

Edit: you have some excessive querying and crawling going on. Here's a little bit of a refactor that will cut down on some of that:

```
$(".confirm_submit").click(function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form"),
        confirmteamnaam = $form.find("input[name='teamnaam']").val(),
        frmnaam = $form.attr("id");

    jConfirm(confirmteamnaam + frmnaam, function(r) {
        if (!r) return false;
        $form.submit();
        return true;
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is correct but it's nice if explained too. `var frmnaam = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');` gets id as string but CSS selector must be added or selector tries to find HTML tag.

Comment: @Terradon - what behavior are you seeing now? Are there any errors?

Comment: i just get the alertmessage with the right text of the variables, when clicking on OK, nothing happens. If i create a mistype in this jquery part, my form will be sent without any confirmation text.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this jConfirm library you're using. What happens if you put an `alert('The value of r is ' + r);` immediately before the `if(!r) return false;` line? That will let us know if the callback is being invoked, and if we're passing that conditional.

Comment: never thought about that: r = false!! so i have to check the library for it. http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/ I use this frequently and always works, except for now. Thanks for giving the clue where it went wrong!

Comment: i am not allowed to give my own answer as my own solution, so i have to do it her. Holy sh*t, this is really incredibale, found the solution...
jConfirm( 'test' + confirmteamnaam  + frmnaam + 'test','bevestig!', function(r) {

i forgot a parameter: bevestig!, i forgot this parameter, that is why r became false!
Adding this parameter was the solution. Thanks again for giving the clue that r was false!